# Nginx ingress controller rate limiting not working

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

```
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-connection: "1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rpm: "20"
```

and the container image version, iam using,
image: `quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.22.0`

trying to send 200 requests in ten mins of range (and per min it is like a 20 requests from a single ipaddress) and after that it has to refuse the requests.

Answer (score 1):

Which nginx ingress version are you using ?  please use quay.io/aledbf/nginx-ingress-controller:0.415 and then check, Also Please look at this link - https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1839

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this  `limit-connection:` to `limit-connections:`

For more info check [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/nginx-0.22.0/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#rate-limiting)

If doesn't help, please put your commands or describe that how are you testing your connection limits.

Comment: did the improvements and its not working. please see the below answer, it describes how i am doing the things.

Answer (score 0):

```
I changed it to the limit-connections, I am mentioning the annotations in the ingress yml file and applying it and i can in the nginx conf the following 

`worker_rlimit_nofile 15360;
    limit_req_status                503;
    limit_conn_status               503;
    # Ratelimit test_nginx
    # Ratelimit test_nginx `
   ` map $whitelist_xxxxxxxxxxxx $limit_xxxxxxxxxx {
    limit_req_zone $limit_xxxxxxxx zone=test_nginx_rpm:5m rate=20r/m;
            limit_req zone=test_nginx_rpm burst=100 nodelay;
            limit_req zone=test_nginx_rpm burst=100 nodelay;
            limit_req zone=test_nginx_rpm burst=100 nodelay;`


when i kept this annotations, 

 ` nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-connections: "1" 
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rpm: "20" `

I can see the above burst and other things in the nginx conf file, can you please tell me these make any differences ?
```

Comment: Hi Raja, please do not add more answers to your topic if you are providing more info. Just update the original post.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that could be making you experience rate-limits higher than configured: burst and nginx replicas.

### Burst

As you have already noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54426317/3477266, nginx-ingress adds a burst configuration to the final config it creates for the rate-limiting.

The burst value is always 5x your rate-limit value (it doesn't matter if it's a `limit-rpm` or `limit-rps` setting.)

That's why you got a `burst=100` from a `limit-rpm=20`.

You can read here the effect this burst have in Nginx behavior: https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/#bursts

But basically it's possible that Nginx will not return 429 for all request you would expect, because of the burst.

The total number of requests routed in a given period will be `total = rate_limit * period + burst`

### Nginx replicas

Usually nginx-ingress is deployed with Horizontal Pod AutoScaler enabled, to scale based on demand. Or it's explicitly configured to run with more than 1 replica.

In any case, if you have more than 1 replica of Nginx running, each one will handle rate-limiting individually.

This basically means that your rate-limit configuration will be multiplied by the number of replicas, and you could end up with rate-limits a lot higher than you expected.

There is a way to use a `memcached` instance to make them share the rate-limiting count, as described in: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#global-rate-limiting